# Accessing an application on EKS behind an internal NLB from on-prem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, istio

I am trying to reach an application on an EKS cluster via an internal NLB. The request is timing out.

- the EKS is in a non-routable cidr (10.0.0.0/16)
- the NLB is in the routable 10.1.0.0/16 (from on-prem) cidr and it forwards the traffic to the backend via the Istio Ingress Gateway
- the on-prem cidr is something like 10.2.0.0/16 and it can talk to 10.1.0.0/16 where the NLB is located (routable cidr)
- the application is reachable from inside the VPC (via the same NLB)
- the application is not reachable from on-prem (via the same NLB) - timing out
- I can hit another application (not EKS) via an internal ALB in the same routable cidr (same port 443) with the backend in the non-routable cidr (hence proving the connectivity)
- I can also reach VPC endpoints in the same VPC routable cidr
- the connection from on-prem to AWS VPC cidr is going through a Direct Connect connection
- there is no access to the internet

I am thinking that perhaps how the NLB forwards the traffic might have an impact on this. DNS is resolving to the NLB IPs but won't connect. I can't telnet to the NLB IPs either though.

Since EKS is in 10.0.0.0/16, it can talk to 10.1.0.0/16 which is routed locally in the vpc but it can't talk to on-prem 10.2.0.0/16. Then the NLB does not terminate the connection but lets the traffic through with the source IP, hence that IP won't be allowed in the EKS cidr.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have VPN setup? Internal nlb can't be accessed using Internet.

Comment: There is a Direct Connect connection. I can reach a few ALBs and vpc endpoints in the routable block via the same DX. But I can't reach the NLB.

Comment: How about the DNS setting? Routing is not enough, you need to configure DNS (`Inbound resolver on route53` I think)

Comment: @FranxiHidro I can resolve DNS from on-prem. I have a CNAME that points to the NLB DNS, it resolves to the NLB ips but then times out. It works for ALB though, same setup.

Comment: Can you do a ``curl -v internal-nlb-domain-name`` and update the result in your question? I guess you have Transit GW and forget to update on it.

Comment: @FranxiHidro I can't resolve NLB DNS from on-prem, I have on-prem DNS associated with my private DNS zones (*.subdomain.shared.corp.net). That's how I resolve the CNAMES.

Comment: You are using the same domain on both cloud and on-prem? How can ``on-prem DNS associate with private DNS hosted zone`` on AWS? You can resolve your domain-name.com but cannot resolve the NLB domain (what is the DNS server in these cases?). That's why I mention ``Inbound resolver on route53``.

Comment: @FranxiHidro I can resolve anything on *.subdomain.shared.corp.net in the cloud, from on-prem. DNS is not an issue, as I mentioned the curl command (using the CNAME) finds the correct NLB ips. Using the same for ALBs which connect to them via CNAME with curl or in the browser. Does not work for the NLB.

Comment: You said ``I can't resolve NLB DNS from on-prem``. Just show the result from curl -v, It is too difficult with these guys.

Comment: I can't resolve NLB DNS directly, that's why I am using CNAME such as "curl -v eks-nlb1.subdomain.shared.corp.net". Curl is trying to connect to all 3 NLB ips and then is timing out. "curl -v alb.subdomain.shared.corp.net" works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the on-prem CIDR is not associated with the EKS CIDR. Hence the source IP won't be allowed in the EKS CIDR. But that is what the NLB will do. Hence I had to make sure that that is not enabled.

Solution: The "Preserve Client IP" option in the target group should be set to DISABLED.

Answer (score 0):

The NLB's are transparent and don't have any security group, check if the application hosted on EKS has the on prem CIDR range allowed for that port. This security group could be attached to the EKS pod or to the EKS worker node group.

Comment: yes, I have already checked and allowed all traffic from the on-prem cidr into the worker nodes. NACL is also allowing the traffic. But there is no change.